# Heroku logs are flooded with the log-runtime-metrics

Tags: heroku, logging

The set of logs below is appearing every 20 seconds on my heroku app log.

```
heroku[web.1]: source=web.1 dyno=heroku.... sample#load_avg_1m=0.00
heroku[web.1]: source=web.1 dyno=heroku.... sample#memory_total=18.06MB sample#memory_rss=17.37MB sample#memory_cache=0.69MB sample#memory_swap=0.00MB sample#memory_pgpgin=7511pages sample#memory_pgpgout=2888pages sample#memory_quota=512.00MB
```

I've found out these are Runtime metrics logs (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/log-runtime-metrics), not error logs.

I've tried these commands to disable this function but it didn't make any sense.

```
$ heroku labs:disable log-runtime-metrics
$ heroku restart
$ git commit --allow-empty -m "Force Heroku build."
$ git push heroku master
```

I also checked my heroku labs feature conditions by the command below.

```
$ heroku labs
```

It says log-runtime-metrics is not activated.

I completely don't have any idea for the cause of this behavior.

Comment: I ran into the same issue with a new app I deployed to Heroku yesterday. I would expect it is a bug on their end but haven't found any official resources on that yet. Did you try contacting their support?

Comment: I'm glad to encounter a guy who has the same issues.
I tried to report this case to the official, but it seems there are no means for free-plan users to contact them directly.
This is why I register stackoverflow.